# How to get rid of a word in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

Currently I am having this kind of a list:

`['Rating 3.9577555469954', 'Rating 3.730694980695', 'Rating 4.0717869548437', 'Rating 4.0597014925373', 'Rating 3.7323798994975']`

I am trying to get rid of the 'Rating ' part. How do I achieve that in the end there are only numbers/floats in my list?

Comment: `[float(x.strip("Rating ")) for x in yourList]`

Comment: Thanks it worked! :)

Comment: What did you try, and what exactly was the problem with it?

Comment: I am trying to web-scrapy with scrapy. Currently I am was getting with the command "response.css('span.rating::attr(aria-label)').extract()" a list with these strings. Would there be a more esthetic way to get only floats?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to jordanm's answer using `regex`:

```
import re
strings = ['Rating 3.9577555469954', 'Rating 3.730694980695', 'Rating 4.0717869548437', 'Rating 4.0597014925373', 'Rating 3.7323798994975']
floats = [float(re.findall('([0-9]+[,.]+[0-9]+)',x)[0]) for x in strings]
print(floats)
```

Outputs:

```
[3.9577555469954, 3.730694980695, 4.0717869548437, 4.0597014925373, 3.7323798994975]
```

This will capture all digits, regardless of "Rating" or other word that might precede it. (in case there's `Ratings` for example)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through list and strip the value. I like to use UPPER or LOWER to catch all cases.

```
my_list = ['Rating 3.9577555469954', 'Rating 3.730694980695',
           'Rating 4.0717869548437', 'Rating 4.0597014925373', 'Rating 3.7323798994975']

new_list = []

for value in my_list:
    new_list.append(value.upper().strip('RATING').strip())

print(new_list)
```

Results:

```
['3.9577555469954', '3.730694980695', '4.0717869548437', '4.0597014925373', '3.7323798994975']
```